# Disable NavHost animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any option to disable the CrossFade animation when navigating in Jetpack Compose?

In the source code, I see that the CrossFade is simply hardcoded, and in AnimatedNavHost from "accompanist" I can't locate such an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging i found the following solution:

In the AnimatedNavHost composable, we need to specify 'empty' transitions.

```
 AnimatedNavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = "main",
                    enterTransition = { _, _ -> EnterTransition.None},
                    exitTransition = { _, _ -> ExitTransition.None}
                )
```

Comment: If it is a version before 2.7.0, it is valid, but in later versions, a zoom animation will appear. There seems to be no solution. At the same time, I also saw that some people also have this problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297258205#comment1

Answer (score 1):

These parameters appeared in NavHost. In `build.gradle`:

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"

Requires Android target SDK 34.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version below 2.7.0, then you can use this method to remove the animation

```
NavHost(
     navController = navController,
     startDestination = startDestination,
     modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize(),
     enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
     exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
     popEnterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
     popExitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
 )
```

If you are using version 2.7.0 or above, this version seems to trigger a scaling animation that cannot be removed.

You can only upgrade androidx.compose.ui in the gradle file:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-alpha03")
```

and then it will be normal.

I saw others having this happen here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297258205#comment1